# ORACLE SKEWNESS

Tags: oracle, skew

In Oracle SQL Developer , how do we find the skewness of data in a table ?

Comment: How do you define skewness?  Are you looking for columns with histograms, listed in `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.HISTOGRAM`?

Comment: Hi , Jon Heller, Yes.  It can be columns with histograms

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 20c supports SKEWNESS aggregate functions:

> [New Analytical and Statistical Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/newft/new-analytical-and-statistical-aggregate-functions.html)
>
> **SKEWNESS** functions SKEWNESS_POP and SKEWNESS_SAMP are measures of asymmetry in data. When skewness is positive this means data is skewed to right. When skewness is negative this means data is distributed to left.
>
> ---
>
> [SKEWNESS_POP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/SKEWNESS_POP.html#GUID-DF34158F-B681-4933-BA27-0A3885A9F43C)
>
> SKEWNESS_POP is an aggregate function that is primarily used to determine symmetry in a given distribution.